# How can I exclude data from mongo db whose value is ""

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have one excel sheet whose few row values are blank. In `MongoDB` that values goes in the form of ""(when view in edit mode)
When I try to retrieve the data excluding "" values. I am still getting that.

My query is as below.

```
DrivetestdataLTE.find({
    latitude: { $ne:"" },
    longitude: { $ne:"" }}, { '_id': 0 }).lean().exec();
}
```

Saved data:

---

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("5de751d04a8590a009d4905a"),
    "log_hash" : "2.08E+17",
    "Time" : "33:23.7",
    "latitude" : "",
    "longitude" : "",
```

---

Comment: The query seems fine. Nevertheless, Can you provide some more info like show us some saved data. How is it saved?

Comment: Added in question part.

Comment: The query is fine. Nothing wrong with it. I have tried in the mongodb itself. Try to run the same query in MongoDB console and check what happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
DrivetestdataLTE.find({
    latitude: { $ne:"" },
    longitude: { $ne:"" },{ '_id': 0 }}).exec();
}
```

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: you include parenthesis extra.

Answer (score 0):

you can find records, if field exist and value is empty

```
DrivetestdataLTE.find({ latitude: { $exists: true, $not: {$size: {"$gt":0}} }, longitude: { $exists: true, $not: {$size: {"$gt":0}} } })
```

or you can find if field is not exist

```
DrivetestdataLTE.find({ latitude: { $exists: false }, longitude: { $exists: false }  })
```